# WHMCS page Dont show domain list when no admin is logged in?

Tags: whmcs

Whmcs = 7.3

admin is logged in in the backend,in registration page :
show domain list and price:

[When it's ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFogn.jpg)

but if no admin is logged in in the backend, show no domain list..

[Not Ok!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LktGv.jpg)

i dump the array of pricing in the template file i got the error :

> "An admin user is required to invoke Internal API Commands"

How to show the list even the admin is not logged in ??

Comment: Is that custom code or default WHMCS page?

Comment: default WHMCS page...

Comment: It is working for me. Try deactivate all addons and see if it is working.